# How can I specify which team receives what alerts from opsgenie?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, alert, prometheus-alertmanager, opsgenie

So to be more clear, we have some infrastructure and application related alerts set on Prometheus which is running on cluster A. Also, we have 2 teams one is devops and the other one is app team. I would like to make sure that devops team only receives the alerts those related to infra and app team receives the alerts those related to application.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi  Oscar, you can routes your alerts based on the labels.